# Testing classic internal ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, elastic-load-balancer

I have configured and passed the health check for my AWS ELB(load balancer), but I was trying to do a ping or send a packet to the tcp port 9300 there is no ip address for the ELB. 
I have an EC2 instance at the end of the ELB which has Elasticsearch running on it.

The ELB that I configured is an internal ELB so it doesn't have a public IP address for it. 
I was wondering if there is a way I can ssh? or do something to ping the ELB? 
I am pretty new to AWS and read all the trouble shooting from AWS official website, but couldn't find a solution.

The goal that I am trying to achieve is to test whether my internal Amazon EC2 load Balancer is working properly. 
I got the internal ELB ip address with the ping command, however, I am not able to ping or crul to that IP address. 
I what to know what I am doing wrong. 
Is it the way that I want to access a private network is in correct?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do/achieve? Are you testing the connectivity to Elasticsearch? Feel free to Edit your question to add more detail.

Answer (score 1):

An Elastic Load Balancer is presented as a single service, but actually consists of several Load Balancing servers spread across the subnets and Availability Zones you nominate.

When connecting to an Elastic Load Balancer, you should **always use the DNS Name** of the Elastic Load Balancer. This will then resolve into one of the several servers that are providing the load balancing service.

Load Balancers are designed to **pass requests and return responses**. The next time a user sends a request, it might be sent to a different back-end service. Thus, it is good for web-type traffic but not suitable for situations requiring a permanent connection, such as SSH. You can configure **sticky sessions** for HTTP connections that will use cookies to send the user to the same back-end server if required.

The classic Elastic Load Balancer also supports **TCP protocol**, but these requests are distributed in a round-robin fashion to the back-end servers so they are also not suitable for long-lasting sessions.

**Bottom line:** They are great for request/response traffic that needs to be distributed across multiple back-end servers. They are not suitable for SSH.

Site-note: Using PING to test services often isn't a good idea. **Ping is turned off in Security Groups by default** since it can expose services and isn't good from a security perspective. You should test connectivity by connecting via the expected protocols (eg HTTP requests) rather than using Ping. This applies to testing EC2 connectivity, too.

Comment: Note also that ELBs don't respond to pings even if you allow it in the security group settings.